# (Precise) behavior of $f(x)=\frac{1}{x-x\log(x)}$ for $0<x<1$.

Tags: calculus

**Question**

What is the behavior of $f(x)=\frac{1}{x-x\log(x)}$ for $0<x<1$?

**Attempt**

I know that the Taylor series does not exist for $f(x)$ at $x=0$. However, when I look at the [graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F(x-xlog(x))%20%20on%20(0,1%5D) of this function between $0$ and $1$ I feel that it decays exponentially (or like $1/x^n$) to $1$ as $x \rightarrow 1^-$. Is there any way of saying how fast it decays in this interval? I know that the Taylor expansion for $f(x)$ at $x=1$ is $1+1/2(x-1)^2+\mathcal{O}(x-1)^3$ but I actually want to say something like "$f(x)$ decreases exponentially in the interval $(0,1]$". Is this possible to say?

Sorry if my question is a bit informal. I do not know the mathematical terms necessary to express this idea.

Comment: Around $1$, it seems like you have answered your question. (it decays like $(x-1)^2$ as $x$ goes to $1$). Are you interested in the behavior around $0$? Phrased in another way, are you interested in the growth of the function as $x\to0^+$?

Comment: @Clayton yes this is what I am interested in. I am wondering if we can state this behavior in simple terms (perhaps as exponential or $x^{-n}).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x-x\ln(x)=x(1-\ln(x))$ and since $\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}\ln(x)=-\infty$ then the $1$ is negligeable.

So $f(x)\sim\frac1{x\ln(x)}$ near $0^+$ also $x^{\alpha}\ln(x)\to 0$ for any $\alpha>0$ so the behaviour is very similar to $\frac1x$.

Near $1$ you already found the behaviour.

But beside these two critical points, we cannot say much except that it goes from something in $\frac 1x$ near $0$ to something in $\frac 1{x^2}$ near $1$ (not considering the translations).

Answer (score 1):

One of fundamental inequalities on logarithm is:
$$ 1 - \frac1x \leq \log (x) \leq x-1 \quad\text{for all}\quad x > 0$$ Using if for your problem, you then have $$1 \leq \frac{1}{x-x\log(x)}\leq \frac 1{x(2-x)}$$